# В каких случаях аргументы функции необходимы?

Tags: php

Есть такой аргумент (пустой):

```
function a(){
    $c = $a + $b;
    return $c;
}
```

и такой:

```
function a($a,$b){
    $c = $a + $b;
    return $c;
}
```

Чем вторая функция лучше первой? 
Я знаю что вторая вызывается так: a(1,2);

Но для первой же тоже можно делать так (будет аналогичен второму):

```
$a = 1;
$b = 2;
function a(){
    $c = $a + $b;
    return $c;
}
```

Или разница не только в этом?

---

**Перенесено из меток:** Речь о PHP больше 5-ой версии

Comment: Представьте, что вам надо сложить 3 числа этой функцией и при этом не испортить изначальных значений `a` и `b`. С параметрами все просто `a( a(1,2), 3 )`, а с глобальными переменными у вас не выйдет, надо будет где то сохранять предыдущие значения, потом восстанавливать. И все время держать  в голове, что параметры для a() надо положить именно в эти две переменные. А для x() положить в другие. Про многопоточные приложения в которых одновременно два потока могут использовать a() я вообще молчу ...

Comment: Думаю, лучше говорить о том, что вторая функция является "чистой" - то есть, ее результат зависит только от входных параметров. А это значит, что ее можно и тестировать, и оптимизировать (с точки зрения транслятора или в php уже сделали простенький компилятор?) и много много чего.

Чистые функция предпочтительны в любом языке программировании, не только php и код от них стает только лучше.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Предложенный вами вариант не будет аналогичен функции с параметрами

```
<?php
$a = 1;
$b = 2;
function a(){
  $c = $a + $b;
  return $c;
}
echo a(); // 0
```

Добиться аналогичного поведения можно только объявив переменные глобальными

```
<?php
$a = 1;
$b = 2;
function a(){
  global $a, $b;
  $c = $a + $b;
  return $c;
}
echo a(); // 3
```

Глобальная переменная - это плохо. В таком коротком примере это не очевидно, но в большой программе изменив где-то переменную `$a` вы влияете не сотни вызовов функции `a()` по всей программе. Если что-то пошло не так - отлаживать и исправлять ситуацию очень дорого и сложно - в одном месте чините, в другом тут же что-то ломается.

В случае использования параметров - этого не случается, так как в этом случае параметры изолированы в небольшом участке кода. По возможности лучше вообще избегать глобальных переменных и всегда использовать параметры (исключение - объектно-ориентированное программирование, где переменные объекта изолированы в объекте).

Answer (score 2):

```
php -r '$a = 1; $b = 2; function a(){ $c = $a + $b; return $c;} echo a();'
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: a in Command line code on line 1
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: b in Command line code on line 1
0
```

ошибки-ошибочки, а у вас вопрос неправильный. прежде чем задавать вопросы, включите, пожалуйста, показ ошибок или запускайте php через консоль.